# How to set the custom env file when archiving the build with Xcode react-native-dotenv

Tags: xcode, react-native

I have followed multiple env files in the app.

- .env.development
- .env.production
- .env-staging

I am using react-native-dotenv (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv) package to do that.

I have set three different values for the API_BASE_URL since I need to connect to the backend according to the environment.
currently working with debug mode by setting environment like this => APP_ENV=staging react-native start

My question is when I release a build using Xcode archive, how to set the .env.staging file values? it is always picking the .env.production values. I need to get a build that app connected to the staging backend URL

Answer (score 3):

You need archive by option targets (in Xcode).
Firstly you should create targets for your environment (duplicate main target and rename). After that you can choice which environment to build.